# Google colab convolutional neural net is really slow

Tags: google-colaboratory

So I built a CNN in google colab thinking the GPU would be of great help to reducing the huge training time. I'd made sure I was connected to a GPU, and I had my training and test image datafolders (~5000 images) imported from my google drive, but when I actually ran the code I got an estimated time of completing a single epoch to be 25 hours! Not sure if it's the fact I uploaded my image folders via google drive or not, but I would appreciate any help I could get for this problem.

Comment: Please provide example code. There is no way for anyone to help you otherwise.

Comment: Copy the data from google drive to colab drive. The read from google drive is very slow.

Comment: 50-100 times slower!!!!